# Implement a circle on a line with shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a test project with react.I want implement a card with a half circle as follow:

[image]

I tried implement this but I could not. This is my implement picture:

[image]

I think mycircle shadow is wrong.

This is the html and CSS code:

```css
.card__container{
  padding:1.75rem;
  margin-top:1.25rem;
  margin-bottom:2.5rem;
  margin-left:2.5rem;
  margin-right:2.5rem;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.08);
}

.card__container:after{
content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    top: 110px;
    left: -10px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid crimson;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
```

```html
<div className="card__container">

</div>
```

I would appreciate very much, if any one can help.

Comment: I would suggest to create a custom-border with a tool like Photoshop and use it for your border.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner shadow for :before and use :before elements left side to  to hide outer box's shadow:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .card-container {
        padding: 1.75rem;
        margin-top: 1.25rem;
        margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
        margin-left: 2.5rem;
        margin-right: 2.5rem;
        position: relative;
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
        height: 60vh;
        width: 50vw;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98);
      }

      .card-container:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        top: 50px;
        left: -15px;
        height: 30px;
        border-top-right-radius: 50%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
        background-color:white;
        box-shadow: inset -7px 0 8px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card-container">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```